# How to resolve "SHUT_RDWR undeclared error" in shutdown() function to close the listening socket?

Tags: c, sockets

I am doing socket programming. I have created two .c files. One is called `server.c` and the other one is `client.c`. I want to test how socket programming works.

My `server.c` code is given below:

```
/*
 * server.c
 *
 *  Created on: 10 Oct 2022
 *      
 */
#include<Winsock2.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h> // Provides access to POSIX APIs
#define PORT 8080

int main()
{

    // Creating stuctures for port address
    struct sockaddr_in address; // sockaddr_in is the name of structure

    // declaring server and client socket and some variables
    int server_socket;
    int valread;
    int new_socket;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; // Creating an empty buffer to read data
    char* hello ="Hello from Raza..";

    // Creating a server socket
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // If creating of socket is not successful
    if(server_socket < 0){
        perror("socket failed!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Populating the components of sockaddr_in structure
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Binding the socket to the IP Address
    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&address,sizeof(address))<0){
        perror("Bind Failed!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Putting the socket in LISTENING state
    if (listen(server_socket, 3) < 0){
        perror("Listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((new_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0){
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Reading data from the socket into the buffer
    valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    // Sending data to socket
    send(new_socket, hello, strlen(hello), 0);
    printf("Hello message sent\n");

    // Closing the socket
    close(new_socket);
    // closing the listening socket
    shutdown(server_socket, SHUT_RDWR);
    return 0;

    }
```

But the last function where I am shutting down the socket, I am getting the error that the SHUT_RDWR is undeclared. Error is shown below:

```
server.c: In function 'main':
server.c:71:26: error: 'SHUT_RDWR' undeclared (first use in this function)
  shutdown(server_socket, SHUT_RDWR);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
server.c:71:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

I read that the shudown function is that part of `sys/socket.h` library. but when I include that also in my program using

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
```

Then I get the following error:

```
server.c:13:23: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
 #include<sys/socket.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

And if I remove the `shutdown()` line of code, then I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\RAZAJA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGyb5QN.o:server.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `socket@12'
C:\Users\RAZAJA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGyb5QN.o:server.c:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `htons@4'
C:\Users\RAZAJA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGyb5QN.o:server.c:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `bind@12'
C:\Users\RAZAJA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGyb5QN.o:server.c:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `listen@8'
C:\Users\RAZAJA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGyb5QN.o:server.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `accept@12'
C:\Users\RAZAJA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGyb5QN.o:server.c:(.text+0x199): undefined reference to `send@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have mentioned the solutions I tried and their responses. What I read in some questions, is that if someone uses MinGW on windows then `sys/socket.h` doesn.t work. so then `ws2tcpip` must be used. So I included that (can be seen in the code).

Can someone please tell me what can be the solution here problem here? What mistake I am doing?

**Additional Information:**
Editor Used: Visual Studio Code,
Compilor Used: gcc using MinGW

Comment: The documentation you are reading is for Linux. Read MS-Windows' documentation, instead, which uses non-standard values.

Comment: Not only that, but Windows uses `SOCKET` for sockets, not `int`.   And on 64-bit Windows, `SOCKET` is a 64-bit value while `int` is a 32-bit value.  There are other differences, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said in the comments, you are reading the documentation for Linux rather than for Windows OS.

In the [WinAPI documentation for sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-shutdown), the `shutdown()` function is as follows:

```
int WSAAPI shutdown(
  [in] SOCKET s,
  [in] int    how
);
```

while the `int how` paramater can be:

```
SD_RECEIVE 0 - Shutdown receive operations.

SD_SEND 1 - Shutdown send operations.

SD_BOTH 2 - Shutdown both send and receive operations.
```

**So in your case**, use:

```
// closing the socket
shutdown(server_socket, SD_BOTH);
```